# How to detect the origin of a query execution in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, sql-execution-plan, sql-query-store

We have a SQL Server DB that is filled with records from two external applications that have the ability to execute queries against this DB. Both apps are black boxes for us, we don't have access to the code.
We would like to know each execution of these queries from which application it is called.
We have detected when and how often the queries are executed thanks to the Query Store, but we do not know the origin of each execution.
Is there any way to find out?

Comment: In short, no. While Query Store does have [more information available than is displayed graphically](https://learn.microsoft.com/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/query-store-catalog-views-transact-sql), it does not track the provenance of queries. For that you'd have to set up an extended event session or profiler trace; you can filter on plan handle in that.

Comment: If the applications are ADO.NET based and store their connection strings in their .config file(s) then you could add `;ApplicationName=App1` and `;ApplicationName=App2` to their connection strings which would allow you to filter/monitor them separately via SQL Profiler, Extended Events, etc. REF: [ApplicationName property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnectionstringbuilder.applicationname). Other connection libraries use different keywords, e.g.: ODBC uses `;APP=App1`, so check their specific documentation for details.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answers. I'll check it and I let you know.